# Can this Function Be Written with Reduce()?

Tags: javascript

I have a couple functions to first get a total from each object in an array (`getHours`) and then get the sum of totals (`getTotalHours`). Can the `getTotalHours` function be simplified using `reduce()`?

```js
const myActivities = [
   {
    activityID: "3f4473c4-2a79-11ea-978f-2e728ce88125",
    activityName: "Sleeping",
    segmentLength: 3,
    segments: [true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true],
    color: "#2AD33F",
    sort: 1,
  }, {
    activityID: "3f4473c4-2a79-11ea-978f-2e728ce88126",
    activityName: "Eating",
    segmentLength: 3,
    segments: [false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false],
    color: "#EDF11A",
    sort: 2,
  }, {
    activityID: "3f4473c4-2a79-11ea-978f-2e728ce88127",
    activityName: "Projects",
    segmentLength: 3,
    segments: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    color: "#D3412A",
    sort: 3,
  }, {
    activityID: "3f4473c4-2a79-11ea-978f-2e728ce88128", 
    activityName: "Day Job",
    segmentLength: 3,
    segments: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    color: "#2D69E2",
    sort: 4,
  }, {
    activityID: "3f4473c4-2a79-11ea-978f-2e728ce88185",
    activityName: "Commuting",
    segmentLength: 3,
    segments: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    color: "#D32AD1",
    sort: 5,
  }, {
    activityID: "3f4473c4-2a79-11ea-978f-2e728ce88129",
    activityName: "Leisure",
    segmentLength: 3,
    segments: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false],
    color: "#FB8F17",
    sort: 6,
  },
]

function getHours(activity) {
  return activity.segments.filter(seg => seg).length;
}

function getTotalHours() {
  let sum = 0;
  myActivities.forEach(function(activity) {
    sum += getHours(activity);
  });
  return sum;
}

console.log(getTotalHours());
```

Comment: yes - have you tried/

Comment: @DanielA.White yes I'm unable to get valid syntax

Comment: `myActivities.reduce(getHours)` gives me `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: `return myActivities.reduce(getHours());` and I get `Cannot read property 'segments' of undefined`

Comment: `return myActivities.reduce(activity => getHours(activity));` gives me `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
myActivities.reduce((acc, v) => acc +  v.segments.filter(seg => seg).length, 0);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. That's what I was looking for. I used specifically `return myActivities.reduce((sum, activity) => sum + getHours(activity), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the method like this,

```js
function getTotalHours() {
  return myActivities.reduce((sum, activity) => {
    return sum + getHours(activity)
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var total = 0;

    total=myActivities.reduce((sum, activity, index, arr) => {
      sum += getHours(activity);
      return sum;
    }, 0)

    console.log(total);
```

Comment: this answer needs explanation

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).